# $watch event not triggering on element which is initially invisible

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular ui datepicker element which is initially hidden and whose I want to detect date change.

```
<div ng-if="titleVisible">
  <input type="text" readonly 
    class="form-control" 
    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
        is-open="mydp.opened" editable="false" 
            datepicker-options="dateOptions"
            date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
            ng-required="true"
             /> <span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                ng-click="openDate($event)">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
            </span>
```

I have this watcher defined:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.dt },
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(oldValue != newValue) //needed to avoid call on init
                console.log('dt has changed from '+oldValue+' to '+newValue);
        }
       );
```

this watcher never triggers and the console log never shows.
Anyway, by removing that ng-if from component definition (thus making it initially visible) it works.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` creates a child scope. When you are trying to watch `name` from the parent scope, it does not see the changes because `name` gets created in the child scope of `ng-if`.

One solution would be to initialize an object in the parent scope, and then make `dt` a property of that.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObj = {};

  $scope.$watch('myObj.dt', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if(oldValue != newValue) //needed to avoid call on init
         console.log('dt has changed from '+oldValue+' to '+newValue);  
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-if="titleVisible">
  <input type="text" readonly 
    class="form-control" 
    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="myObj.dt"
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UmXqZDshVHOOLVYzZRZp?p=info

Using `ng-hide` instead of `ng-if` should also work.